# change to JGoodies look and feel

Tags: java, look-and-feel, jgoodies

I am trying to change the look and feel to JGoodies Windows.

I added the libraries (`jgoodies-common-1.8.1.jar` / `jgoodies-looks-2.7.0.jar`) and I am able to run the application. I tried a lot of look and feels and the most look similar. But none looks like the one from the demo software (http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/demos). I also tried different ways to set it. When I try to change the theme, there is also no effect but I do not need it.

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(newcom.jgoodies.looks.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel());  
// UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

I get the L&F from the system, so the two lines above have the same effect.

This is my L&F
[image: This is my L&F]

Demo Version, select L&F
[image: Demo Version, select L&F]

L&F Demo Version
[image: L&F Demo Version]

Comment: Shouldn't both Windows look and feels look like Windows anyways? Are you sure the demos (which I can't run) are using the Windows LaF?

Comment: I don't think so, look at the screenshot i posted. Sorry for the formatting, it didnt work to post it otherwise.

Comment: Hmm, your LaF looks like that ugly Metal LaF. Are you sure the line where you set the LaF is executed and that there's no other code that resets it? And do you run the demo and your own application with the same JVM?

Comment: It's similar but when I don't change anything the default (metal) is used and it is blue and shaded. No, I haven't much code yet and changes on the L&F are working. Basically I can use plastic, metal and windows. Yes, It's the same. The worst is the combobox.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by setting the L&F *before* creating the components. Actually I thought the L&F could be changed anytime...